# React, display object with nested children, unlimited depth

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to create an object type that has children inside of the same type, is it doable ?

[image]

Comment: Please post your code, not a picture of it.

Comment: it would be nice if you could post the code instead of a picture. why? since it will be easier to just copy your code, modify it and then reply with an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, it is posible to do recursive components. look at this gif:

[image]